# Counting occurences with missing values

Tags: r

I need to count occurences within my dataframe but I am missing some values.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
ID    Year
18941 2015
56511 2010
58185 2016
66183 1999
18863 2003 
26635 2002 
18564 2003
```

And I need to count the occurences of the Years.

I have already managed to get an accurate count with

```
my_count <- data.frame(table(df$Year))
```

But the problem is that the output is missing some values, it kinda looks like this:

```
Var1 Freq
1991 5
1993 4
1996 24
1997 8
1998 6
...
```

And I need to get the missing rows with a count of "0". Is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you print the df with `dput` and add to your question please?

Comment: Hi Chelmy88, the data frame is kind of big, how would I add it? Just as plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` could be:

```
df %>%
 count(Year) %>%
 complete(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year), 1), fill = list(n = 0))

    Year     n
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1999     1
 2  2000     0
 3  2001     0
 4  2002     1
 5  2003     2
 6  2004     0
 7  2005     0
 8  2006     0
 9  2007     0
10  2008     0
11  2009     0
12  2010     1
13  2011     0
14  2012     0
15  2013     0
16  2014     0
17  2015     1
18  2016     1
```

Comment: If I may ask, is it also possible to do this for a selected range of years?

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean by a selected range of years? :)

Comment: Of course! So I have all years in there, and if I see this correctly the code checks for the max and the min value in the column and will make me a new column based on this, but I wanted to do the same for 1998-2011 for another analysis and wanted to ask if this was possible too, because my dataset now goes from 1991-2018 and that is also the output

Comment: You can do `df %>%
 count(Year) %>%
 complete(Year = seq(1998, 2011, 1), fill = list(n = 0))`. Alternatively, you can just filter out the redundant years `df %>%
 count(Year) %>%
 complete(Year = seq(min(Year), max(Year), 1), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
 filter(Year %in% c(1998:2011))`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but it suddenly stopped working. It keeps returning "Error in count(Year): object 'Year' not found".
I checked time and time again and the column "Year" is definitely in the df. Do you know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Update: found the mistake, the `count` function was masked by `plyr`

Answer (score 0):

Base R method:

```
y <- setNames(as.data.frame(seq(min(as.year(df$Year)), max(df$Year))), "Year")
df <- df[2:1]
zz <- merge(y, df, all = TRUE)
zz[is.na(zz)] <- 0
gg <- aggregate(zz, by = list(zz$Year, zz$ID >0),
                FUN = table)
gg$Group.2 <- ifelse(gg$Group.2 == TRUE, gg$Year, 0)
gg <- setNames(gg[1:2], c("Year", "Count"))
gg[with(gg, order(Year)), ]
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID    Year
18941 2015
56511 2010
58185 2016
66183 1999
18863 2003 
26635 2002 
18564 2003', header = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
# > gg[with(gg, order(Year)), ]
# Year Count
# 13 1999     1
# 1  2000     0
# 2  2001     0
# 14 2002     1
# 15 2003     2
# 3  2004     0
# 4  2005     0
# 5  2006     0
# 6  2007     0
# 7  2008     0
# 8  2009     0
# 16 2010     1
# 9  2011     0
# 10 2012     0
# 11 2013     0
# 12 2014     0
# 17 2015     1
# 18 2016     1
```